# How can I maintain relative sizing in Perl/Tk PanedWindows

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I'm working on a Perl/Tk GUI. It will have three main areas. Two of them side by side on top and then another one below the two.

I could just use grid geometry management. The upper two would have a row weight of 2. The lower one would have a weight of 1.

This would be good for the starting position, but the user needs the ability to adjust the sizes.

Looking at the Tk documentation, PanedWindows can also have a weight, but I can't figure out how to access it.

As I have it now, with my Paned frames, the upper and left children are minimum size, everthing else fills the area below and to the right. If I adjust the main window. only the lower and right windows are resize. Worst of all, I can resize the window and make some of the children disappear.

I want to maintain the current relative sizes.

How do I do this? I'm not tied to paned, grid, pack. Whatever works.

Comment: We've struggled with this one quite a bit, and have a solution that works for 2 panes, but as soon as you have a third pane, everything goes haywire.  Will be interested to know of a solution.  Might help to know your Tk version.  Ours is 8.4.

Comment: @TreyJackson: can you share your solution with 2 panes? i suffer from a similar problem and can't seem to find a solution... thanks

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are using frames in Tk. While I have never used Perl/Tk, I am kind of savy html which Tk is probably based on html. So, you might want to look into frames and framesets at [Frames in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) on the W3C site.

It sounds like you need 1 frameset with 2 frames for the top and another frame for the bottom.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: While your efforts to help are appreciated, HTML isn't at all relevant here.